# JQuery CSS Colorful clock

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the following jQuery component:

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/12/colorful-clock-jquery-css/

And need to set it with a transparent background. The CSS I am setting with a background transparent is the following:

```
.clock .bg, .clock .front{
        width:100px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:#252525;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
    }
```

However when I do that the clock does not function as needed as part of the circle on the left side stays visible.

Any suggestions as to how to solve this?

Comment: Code you add a codepen or jsfiddle of the code you are using?

Comment: The tutorial in the link you gave does NOT work in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

it will not be possible to set a transparent background using this clock.

The animation relies on the div's being non-transparent so that they will occlude part of the images used to create the moving dial effects.

See this explanation from the original tutorial, the top left image has a note "Hidden under front left div"
http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/i22.png

Comment: I was more looking at a solution where the javascript is modified and hides anything on the left side when it is not needed to show. Is this possible?